# How to restrict Array by Filename - Powershell v3

Tags: arrays, powershell, filenames, get-childitem

I am trying to use the GCI command to call all the files within a folder bar the ones with "december" in their name.

I would also like to not call files from a subfolder called "months".

Comment: Have you tried the `-exclude` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\somefolder -exclude months,*december*
```

The `Exclude` parameter accepts an array of terms to exclude.  These terms can include wildcard characters.